# Java Applications embedded/Added to website

Tags: java, html

I have made a java application and want to add it to my website. Is that possible at this current age? I heard about the Applet tag but some browsers has stopped supporting that.

Is there another way for me to add my java application to my html pages in a way that every browser can run the java application on their machine when visiting my website?

Thanks

Comment: You can't guarantee all browsers support Java applets, or any Java run in-browser anymore: [Chrome doesn't support Java](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml). I'd recommend just making the app available as a download link. The user would have to run it on their computer, manually.

Comment: That's a good idea. I might actually do that.

Comment: Infact I could do both. No harm there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Maz, you should consider using JSF in this case.